# Forms inside Tables

Tags: php, html, forms

I tried to post this earlier and thought I would check back, awaiting peer review but on my return it had gone, I hope I'm not reposting unnecessarily. I apologized for my long absence on the previous post. I still am finding the following line seems to be troublesome, since everything else ultimately gets inserted into my database:

```
echo "<td>". 'Tags:<input type="text"  name= "MyTag" size="20">'. "</td>";
```

Here are the two files I use, there are no error message, just no entry into the MyTag field in the database:

```
    <?php

    $connect= mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');

    if($connect)
{
 echo("
Connected");
}
else
{
 echo("
Not Connected");
}

mysql_select_db('');

$sql = "select    `rebus_tbl2`.`MyOrder`,`rebus_tbl2`.`Word`,`rebus_tbl2`.`Translation`,`rebus_tbl2`.`Picture`,`rebus_t bl2`.`Person`,`rebus_tbl2`.`Picture2`,`rebus_tbl2`.`Object`,`rebus_tbl2`.`Scene`,`rebus_tbl2`.`Tag`    from `rebus_tbl2`";     



$query = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$query) {
    die(mysql_error());
}



echo "<table border='1'> 

<table bgcolor='#FF7F50'>


<tr>
<th>MyOrder</th>
<th><font color='red'>Word</font></th>
<th>Translation</th>
<th>Picture</th>
<th>Person</th>
<th>Picture2</th>
<th>Object</th>
<th>Scene</th>
<th>Tag</th>
<th> Control Panel
</tr>";




while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 







    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['MyOrder'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Word'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Translation'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" ."<img src=\"". $row['Picture'] ."\" alt=\"\" />". "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Person'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" ."<img src=\"". $row['Picture2'] ."\" alt=\"\" />". "</td>";
    echo "<td>" ."<img src=\"". $row['Object'] ."\" alt=\"\" />". "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Scene'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Tag']. "</td>";

    echo "<td>". '<form method="post" action="Voting_Submission_Form_to_Voting_Table.php">'."</td>" ;
    echo "<td>". 'Tags:<input type="text"  name= "MyTag" size="20">'. "</td>";




         echo "<td>" . '<input type="radio" name = "Likes" Value = "Like" <name> Likes';
         echo "<td>" . '<input type="radio" name = "Adds"  Value = "Name" <name> Adds';
         echo "<td>" . '<input type="radio" name = "Spelling" Value = "Spelling" <name> Spelling';
         echo "<td>" . '<input type="radio" name = "Inappropriate" Value = "Inappropriate" <name> Inappropriate';


         echo "<td>". '<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit" NAME="B1">'."</TD>";


    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";



    ?>
```

And the Voting_Submission_Form_to_Voting_Table.php file

```
<?php

$connect= mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');


if($connect)
{
 echo("
Connected");
}
else
{
 echo("
Not Connected");
}

mysql_select_db('');



$MyOrder = $_Post['MyOrder'];
$MyTag = $_POST['MyTag'];
$Likes = $_POST['Likes'];
$Adds = $_POST['Adds'];
$Spelling = $_POST['Spelling'];
$Inappropriate = $_POST['Inappropriate'];


if($_POST)
{
 echo("
Posted Successfully");
}
else
{
 echo("
Posted Unsuccessfully");
}

$order = "INSERT INTO Voting_Table
       (MyOrder, MyTag, Likes, Adds, Spelling, Inappropriate)
      VALUES
       ('$MyOrder','$MyTag', '$Likes', '$Adds', '$Spelling', '$Inappropriate')";

$result = mysql_query($order);  
if($result)
{
 echo("
Input data is succeed");
}
else
{
 echo("
Input data is fail");
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you want to post the whole table or what? And if so - WHY?

Comment: We need to see what happens to the data once it's posted

Comment: *"does not insert the data inputted from the form"* - Where's the INSERT?  Plus, if this is part of your code `5echo` remove the `5`.

Comment: @Stonz2 Regarding your edit; we don't know if that `5` in the echo is part of the reason why the OP's code is failing. Do a rollback please. Edit: Never mind, I'll do it.

Comment: You do have `<table></table>` tags, correct? If not, add them. Your form won't show without it. Those tags aren't shown in your question/code.

Comment: Note to anyone wanting to edit OP's code. We don't know if the `5` in the echo is part of the reason why the OP's code is failing or not.

Comment: Okay i have sen the edit to your code but i only see a select query instead of an insert, did you forget to add that? Also **using the old mysql database driver has been deprecated**, use should learn to use either mysqli or pdo.

Comment: I am sorry but your question is not structured properly, it does not give us the information we need to help you out. You say you have issues with your insert, then you should post all the code that directly has to do with that insert, be it html, javascript or php along with the errors that are being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you echo the table inside the form instead of the other way around.  While you're at it why don't you just store everything in 1 variable and echo it once unto the page.

You also did not terminate your final "`<tr>`". It should be "`</tr>`".

Also although it wasn't part of your question please try not to use bother upper and lowercase characters when forming your html tags. Stick to using lowercase chars.

However your issue might be with your insert query or your database connection you should have added that to your post, i have not tested this, there may or may not be syntax errors but try it and let me know what happens.

```
<table>
<form method="post" action="Voting_Submission_Form_to_Voting_Table.php">
  <fieldset>
    <?php
      $table = "<tr>";
      $table .= "<td>" . $row['MyOrder'] . "</td>";
      $table .= "<td>" . $row['Word'] . "</td>";
      $table .= "<td>" . $row['Translation'] . "</td>"; 
      $table .= "<td>" ."<img src='". $row['Picture'] ."' alt='' />". "</td>";
      $table .= "<td>" . $row['Person'] . "</td>";
      $table .= "<td>" ."<img src='". $row['Picture2'] ."' alt='' />". "</td>";
      $table .= "<td>" ."<img src='". $row['Object'] ."' alt='' />". "</td>";
      $table .= "<td>" . $row['Scene'] . "</td>";
      $table .= "<td>" . $row['Tag'] . "</td>";
      $table .= "<td>" . "<input type='number' name='UserNumber' size='5'/>". "</td>";
      $table .= "<td>". "<input type='submit' value='submit' name='b1'>"."</td>";
      $table .= "</tr>";
      echo $table;
    ?>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: *"You also did not terminate your final `<tr>`. It should be `</tr>`"* - Good catch on that, that one eluded me, but you did not do it in your answer. It still reads as `$table .= "<tr>";` Now to wait for the OP to respond, which hasn't despite other answer and comments given.

Comment: Lol thanks i could have sworn i put it there must have removed it by mistake.

Comment: You're welcome. I will +1 because of the fix and instructing OP that there may be syntax errors in query.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, and particularly BlankEDjok for your code editing. Unfortunately I could not work out to build your code into the overall code structure. Maybe it would be better for me to indicate more of the original code. I always seem to have particular problems with the following line
    '<form method="post" action="Voting_Submission_Form_to_Voting_Table.php">'

Comment: Yes it would please post that full portion of your code along with your php code you are using to insert your data and also your database connection.

Comment: Apologies I thought I had set up e-mail alerts to indicate when my question was answered. Thanks for all the input so far, especially Blank EDjok. Unfortunately I couldn't incorporate your code without error messages, and I'm not sure how I could include all my other code since it is more than 500 characters for you to review further. There are a number of variables which my existing code contains which I haven't published which might cause your code to require further editing I think. To present all my code, do I need to start a new thread or can I just edit my old one?

Comment: We just need to see see the insert portion not the entire code to be able to help you.  Also to receive more help it would be very helpful if you posted the exact errors you were having especially with my post, that is the only way anyone here can help you out. And no you can just edit you post and include the additional code with a brief description of the edit you made.